# Python re module - repeated symbols limit when using 'or'

Tags: python, regex

I have a question. Lets say there are such patterns:

```
>>> import re
>>> pt ='^a{1,2}$'
>>> re.search(pt, 'aa') # looks ok
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x020B2288>
>>> re.search(pt, 'aaa') # ok too
>>>
```

Now lets try to look for match with another pattern:

```
>>> pt = '^a{1,2}|x$'
>>> re.search(pt, 'a') # this one looks ok
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x020B25D0>
>>> re.search(pt, 'aaax') # (1) Now this one?
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x020B2288>
>>> re.search(pt, 'aaaaaax') # (2) and this one?
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x020B25D0>
>>> re.search(pt, 'aaa') # (3) and this one?
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x020B25D0>
```

(1)(2)(3) To me it looks like it should match string that starts with one or two 'a' or one 'x' or both combinations and ends between these letters, but nothing else. Or I don't get it something? Is it should be like that? Like when you use '|', it ignores what limit is put inside {}?
Can someone explain me this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `$` is affected by the grouping.  Your regex is interpreted as `(^a{1,2})|(x$)`, which matches either "one or two as at the beginning of the string" OR "an x at the end of the string".  If you want to have the `|` apply only to the as and xs, you need to group them:

```
pt = '^(a{1,2}|x)$'
```

Or, if you don't want to capture the group, use a noncapturing group:

```
pt = '^(?:a{1,2}|x)$'
```

Edit: I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to match, but perhaps try:

```
pt = '^(a{1,2}x?|x)$"
```

Comment: But then it matches as 'xor' operation either 'a' part or 'x', but not both. How to make it match either 'a' part or 'x' part or both parts, but nothing else?

Comment: @oerp: Look at my edited answer.  If that's not what you want then you'll need to explain more explicitly what combinations you want to allow.

Answer (score 2):

`^foo|bar$` matches `^foo` or `bar$`.

Comment: So then it does not matter what limit is given to foo?

Comment: What do you mean by "limit given to foo"?

Comment: Well I'm talking about let say a{1,2}. So it says it says there can be only 'a' or 'aa'.

Comment: OK, let's say `foo` is `a{1,2}`. Now what is your question?